# Why React Doesn't Redirect to route?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks, react-router-dom

I am using React And BrowserRoute Component, When I Use this way doesn't Redirect to Route For Example:

```
...//Code
<BrowserRouter>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/" exact component={Home}/>
    <Route path="/profile" exact component={Profile}/>
    <Route path="/login" exact component={Login}/>
  </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

In this Functional Components I have the following Code:

**Login Component**

```
const Login = () => {
    const loginContext = useContext(LoginContext);
    if (loginContext.isAuth) {
        return <Redirect to='/profile' />
    }
    const authUser = () => {
        loginContext.authUser();
    }

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
            ...
   );
```

**Profile Component**

```
const Profile = () => {
    const loginContext = useContext(LoginContext);
    const logOut = () => {
        loginContext.logOut()
        **return <Redirect to='/login' />**
    }
    **if (!loginContext.isAuth) {**
        return <Redirect to='/login' />
    }
    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
            ...
    );
```

If I put some Logic to the **logOut** function when i click button like `<Button ... onClick={logOut} >Log Out</Button>` doesn't redirect to the Login Component
But When **loginContext.isAuth** is false the Component works good and redirect...
I used and not used Switch Component, render at Route render={...} and component={...} but doesnt' work when i want to redirect when I Click the LogOut Button, only when the loginContext.isAuth is true o false...

PSD: Sorry for my English :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `react-router-dom`, correct?
Routing, if you do not need a clickable link but route from code, is best done using the `useHistory` component exposed by `react-router-dom`.

For example:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Profile = () => {
    const loginContext = useContext(LoginContext);
    const history = useHistory();

    const logOut = () => {
        loginContext.logOut()
        history.push({pathname: '/login'});
    }

    if (!loginContext.isAuth) {
        history.push({pathname: '/login'});
    }

    return (
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col">
            ...
    );
```